# PyGit2 - TreeBuilder.insert('name',blobid,GIT_FILEMODE_BLOB) vs index.add( 'path/to/file' )?

Tags: python, git, repository, pygit2

I'm a little confused about how to get started with PyGit2.

When adding files (plural) to a newly created repo, *should* I add them to 
`index.add('path/to/file')`
or would I be better off creating a TreeBuilder and using 
`tb.insert( 'name',oid, GIT_FILEMODE_BLOB )` to add new content ?

If the second case, I am stumped as to how I create the tree object needed to commit to a newly created repo?

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `pygit2.Repository` is called `repo`, try:

```
t_builder = repo.TreeBuilder()
```

More handy info with `help(pygit2.TreeBuilder)` from Python console.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either ways.
I find the `index.add()` method straightforward.

You can fetch all the files to be added or removed to the index using   `Repository.status()`   as a dictionary. The dictionary contains the filename as key and status of file as value. Depending upon the status values deleted files will be needed to be removed from index using `index.remove(filename)`.
Write this index to in-memory tree using `index.write_tree()` which will return a tree-id to be used in `Repository.commit()`.
However for changes to be saved to disk use `index.write()` too.